# Cannot open local Terninal

Tags: flutter, android-studio, terminal, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Trying to open terminal on android studio but it keeps on showing this error

```
Failed to start [/bin/bash, --rcfile, /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in, -i] 


See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in Finder) for the details.
```

Comment: Can you share relevant info from the log?

Comment: Honestly dont know where the log is located

Comment: Is Show Log in Finder clickable? Otherwise, maybe `find ~/ -name idea.log`

Comment: nothing really useful but showing this  : INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found

Comment: Googling led to: [ADB command not found error](https://windowsreport.com/adb-command-not-found/)

Comment: yes, so do you know what i am supposed to do

Comment: No, but that page suggests installing 'the Android SDK Platform-Tools package' so Google for that, and see what you can find.

Comment: ok, thanks, will do that